# Sharing Sitemesh decorator between apps?

Tags: java, dry, sitemesh

In order to adhere to the DRY principle and allow the look and feel of applications to change across my organization without significant redeploys, I would like to share Sitemesh decorators across Java webapps deployed to various app containers.

**Is there any way to do this without extending SiteMesh significantly? If not, is there a good place to customize Sitemesh functionality to allow this (the docs are a bit spotty)?**

*Since Sitemesh 3 seems to be in alpha at this time, this question really is for Sitemesh 2.*